# Python Regex scraping data from a webpage

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

My idea was to explore the Groupon's website to extract the url of the deals. The problem is that I'm trying to do a findall on the Groupon's page to find datas like this: (of this page: http://www.groupon.de/alle-deals/muenchen/restaurant-296)

```
"category":"RESTAURANT1","dealPermaLink":"/deals/muenchen-special/Casa-Lavecchia/24788330", and I'd like to get the 'deals/muenchen-special/Casa-Lavecchia/24788330'.
```

I tried the whole night but I'm unable to find a correct regex. I tried:

```
import urllib2
import re
Page_Web = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.groupon.de/alle-deals/muenchen/restaurant-296').read()
for m in re.findall('category*RESATAURANT1*dealPermaLink*:?/*/*/*/*\d$',Page_Web):
   print m
```

But it doesn't print anything.

Comment: If you have time to look at them, BeautifulSoup and Requests libraries can make scraping in Python a lot easier.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just register to [groupon api](http://www.groupon.com/pages/api) and use it to achieve your goal in a safe, convinient and *legal* way?

Answer (score 1):

In order to extrapolate the block that interest you, I would do this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.groupon.de/alle-deals/muenchen/restaurant-296').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
scriptResults = soup('script',{'type' : 'text/javascript'})
js_block = scriptResults[12]
```

Starting from this you can parse with a regex if you want or try to interprete the js (there are some threads on stackoverflow about that).

Anyway, like the others said, you should use groupon api...

P.S.
The block that you are parsing can be easily parsed as a dictionary, is already a list of dictionary if you look well...

Comment: I succeed, thanks here is what I've done. My Problem was that I didn't understand the regex very well :

import urllib2
import re
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.groupon.de/alle-deals/muenchen/restaurant-296').read()

txt=html

liste = re.findall('category":"RESTAURANT1","dealPermaLink":"/[\w-]*/[\w-]*/[\w-]*/\d*',txt)

print liste

Answer (score -1):

How about changing `RESATAURANT1` to `RESTAURANT1`, for starters?

Comment: Have you at least tried that? There are plenty of other errors in the regex. Downvote.

Comment: Sure, the correct regex is
'category":"RESTAURANT1","dealPermaLink":"/[\w-]*/[\w-]*/[\w-]*/\d*'